docker --mount type=tmpfs memory usage
I am writing because I am wondering if I am wrongly interpretating the docker online documentation. Thus I’d like to understand.
Here is a docker run call
docker run -it --rm --memory=5000m --memory-swap=5000m --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/app,tmpfs-size=25000m ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash

Inside the container, I can see the 25000m allocated to the /app mount point - this is the partial output of the  df -h.
tmpfs                           25G     0   25G   0% /app

This is consistent with the documentation https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/
But I am not able to write more than 5000m on /app (I tested this with dd by writing more files). Apparently, this seems to be not consistent with documentation. Indeed neither https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/  nor https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory report any interaction among
--memory --memory-swap and --mount type=tmpfs
Apparently, it seems that docker is not able to distinguish between the ram allocated (5000m ) and the tmpfs. And when the tempfs reaches the --memory --memory-swap limit, the container is killed. But is this the expected behaviour?
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
Wrapping up..
I was expecting to be able to write up to 25000m to the /app mount point with a container instantiated in this way
docker run -it --rm --memory=5000m --memory-swap=5000m --mount type=tmpfs,destination=/app,tmpfs-size=25000m ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash

But I was not able to go beyond the limit imposed by --memory=5000m --memory-swap=5000m (even if this is not clear from the online documentation)

What was the dd call?

I am not able to execute more than this (1) dd if=/dev/zero of=/app/zero_1.img bs=1G count=2  ---  (2) dd if=/dev/zero of=/app/zero_2.img bs=1G count=2 . Thus I am not able to write more than 3.9G
